# Running Mocha 6 ES6 tests with Babel 7, how to set up?

Tags: npm, mocha.js, babeljs, transpiler

For a library written in ES6/7, I want to compile (to ES5) the library to a dist/ folder. I also want to run the tests (written in ES6/7) for this lib.

My dev dependencies look like this (package.json):

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
  "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
  "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
  "chai": "^4.2.0",
  "mocha": "^6.1.4",
  "sinon": "^7.3.2"
},
```

My build and test scripts looks like this (package.json):

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --require @babel/register",
  "build": "babel src -d dist --presets=@babel/preset-env"
},
```

Running `npm run build` works well. The dist/ folder gets populated with transpiled files.

Running `npm run test` does not seem to work - this is my problem.

```
> mocha --require @babel/register

/Users/dro/Repos/lib/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1163
      else throw err
           ^

ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

*Initially I got an import error, which was resolved by adding .babelrc file.*

Below is my .babelrc file content.

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

I was reading about `regeneratorRuntime` and it got me to [this link about babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) where they explain I shouldn't need that polyfill.

> This will emulate a full ES2015+ environment (no < Stage 4 proposals) and is intended to be used in an application rather than a library/tool.

What is needed to set this up properly?

---

I am not using webpack.

Comment: [Read this answer to understand Babel, in short](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017427/104380)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Testing in ES6 with Mocha and Babel 7. Look here: https://dev.to/bnorbertjs/my-nodejs-setup-mocha--chai-babel7-es6-43ei or http://jamesknelson.com/testing-in-es6-with-mocha-and-babel-6/

```
npm install --save @babel/runtime 
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

And, in .babelrc, add:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for those resources - I've gone through James Knelson's article, since it's from 2015, it's no longer applicable. I will look at dev.to now!

Comment: the article at dev.to is helpful, but still doesn't solve my issue. They are using Mocha 5, where the `--compiler` option is available. In Mocha 6 we may only use `--require` as stated [here in the compilers deprecation article](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation#what-should-i-use-instead-then).

Comment: Read transcript: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-how-to-write-a-javascript-library-adding-es6-support-to-tests-using-mocha-and-babel

Comment: With Babel 7, the `--compilers` flag is deprecated in favour of `--register`, which I'm using above. I've also updated the question with the error after adding a .babelrc file. I'm tinkering around with the test script and seems this also fails `"mocha --require @babel/register @babel/polyfill` (`Error: No test files found: "@babel/polyfill"`), but the package is installed.

Comment: v7 migration article was very informative - I didn't find it until now. Your answer works perfectly - thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [project documentation](https://babeljs.io/en/setup#installation):

```
npm install --save-dev babel-register
```

In your package.json file make the following changes:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require babel-register"
  }
}
```

Some features will require a polyfill:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
```

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require babel-polyfill --require babel-register"
  }
}
```

Comment: This method works, but the steps copied here are not sufficient. Quote from the project document: Great! You've configured Babel but you haven't made it actually do anything. ... In order to enable the preset you have to define it in your .babelrc file, like this:
```{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}```

Comment: side-note, you want to use `@babel/PAKAGE-NAME` not `babel-PACKAGE-NAME`. e.g. `@babel/register` not `babel-register`. Except for a few where you don't get a clean 1-to-1 mapping like that. babel switched from the `babel-` convention to the `@babel/` convention not too long ago. `babel-` packages are maintained, but only `@babel/` packages are getting updated

Answer (score 1):

Below steps are for applying *Babel* transformations & `core-js` polyfills for your tests file:

All transformations are only done per current environment, so only what is needed to be transpiled/polyfilled, will be. Target environments may be defined from a `.browserslist` file or as a property in `package.json` file. ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66234329/104380))

### Step 1: Install packages:

1. `@babel/core`  ([read why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57508875/104380))
2. `@babel/preset-env` ([read why](https://blog.jakoblind.no/babel-preset-env/))
3. `@babel/register` ([read why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428342/104380))
4. `core-js` ([read why](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-core-js-library-and-why-is-it-a-dependency-in-a-lot-of-packages))

> Note that `@babel/polyfill` exists and uses `core-js` under the hood. However, it was deprecated in favor of using `core-js` directly.

### Step 2: Create a [Babel configuration file](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration) `babel.config.js`

(used to be *.babelrc.js* or a *.json* file).
Create this file at the **root-level** of your code.

The most basic configuration (for just testing and **not** bundling) would look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { 
      "corejs": "3.26",   
      "useBuiltIns": "usage"
    }],
};
```

**`corejs`** - This is the polyfills library and should be specified with the minor version, otherwise `x.0` will be used.
It is needed when testing code on rather "old" Node versions, which do not support all of the language methods. This ofc depends on your own usage of such javascript methods. (for example *String.prototype.replaceAll*).

**`useBuiltIns`** - must be set in order for the `corejs` polyfills to be applied. [Read about it in the official docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins).

By default, `@babel/preset-env` will compile your code for the current environment, but you can specify a different environment by setting the "targets" option in the configuration.

---

Ofc, you can add more presets like `@babel/preset-react` for example, if your code it written in React, or any other plugins which are specifically needed for your code.

### Step 3: Connect `mocha` to the babel configuration:

#### In your `package.json` file

Under the `scripts` section, simply write something like this:

```
"test": "mocha \"src/**/*.test.js\""
```

#### Create a `.mocharc.json` file with this content:

```
{
  "exit": true,
  "color": true,
  "require": ["@babel/register"],
  "ignore": "node_modules"
}
```

This will apply *Babel* transformations to all of your test files.

If you need need to apply some special global javascript before/to all of your tests, you can add another file to the `require` setting, for example, [`fixtures.cjs`](https://mochajs.org/#global-teardown-fixtures):

```
"require": ["@babel/register", "fixtures.cjs"],
```

`fixtures.cjs`:

Below example applies a `chai` (popular alongside *Mocha*) plugin for testing DOM-related code:

```js
var chai = require('chai'),
  chaiDOM = require('chai-dom');

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255953/chai-usechaihttp-once-or-in-every-test-file
// https://mochajs.org/#global-teardown-fixtures
exports.mochaGlobalSetup = function () {
    chai.use(chaiDOM);
}
```

---

#### Interesting reads:

- [Babel vs babel-core vs babel-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32544685/104380)
- [How does mocha / babel transpile my test code on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017427/104380)