# Why need @babel-core

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am new to Babel and JS and I wonder when and why to use @babel-core package instead of @babel-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the official babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/):

> Babel is a toolchain that is mainly used to convert ECMAScript 2015+
>   code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript in current and
>   older browsers or environments.

This means that you can write your code in a version that is not compatible in some browsers then babel convert you code to make those browsers 'understand' it. This process of conversion is called compiling.

From [the official babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli):

> Babel comes with a built-in CLI which can be used to compile files
>   from the command line.

This means that @babel-cli comes inside of @babel-core. It is a tool that helps you work with babel. It helps you compile you code using the command line interface.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, the reason I decided to ask this question was that I found out babel package was divided into babel-cli and babel-core. Also, babel-cli should be installed to use babel in cli but babel-core to be used with Node API only. Is that right?. If so then what is node api briefly and how babel-core can be implemented inside node api just simple example. I tried to search what node api is but couldn't find clear article on that.

Comment: To understand what nodejs is I suggest [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8XF6AFGqlc). The example that you seek you can get from [this article](https://www.codementor.io/iykyvic/writing-your-nodejs-apps-using-es6-6dh0edw2o). Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: accepted your answer, just a mere question will babel work if we do not install @babel/core?

Comment: No it will not.