# chai.use(chaiHttp); Once or in every test file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

Adding Chai HTTP (https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) to a Node project tests.

Using the plugin (as in the documentation) is using:

```
var chai = require('chai')
  , chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

I'm wonder if I need to add `chai.use(chaiHttp);` in every test file I'm using chaiHttp? or can I setup chaiHttp once in one of the tests?

can it be in a common file?

Comment: Personally, I have a separate `setup.js` file in my test folder, where I do all these kinds of initialization. Furthermore, there are a few general actions attached to the global `before()`/`beforeEach()` and `after()`/`afterEach()` handles.

Answer (score 1):

From `mocha` v8.2.0, you can use [https://mochajs.org/#global-fixtures](https://mochajs.org/#global-teardown-fixtures).

global fixtures:

> Are guaranteed to execute once and only once

You can use [TEST FIXTURE DECISION-TREE WIZARD THING](https://mochajs.org/#test-fixture-decision-tree-wizard-thing).

> This flowchart will help you decide which of hooks, root hook plugins or global fixtures you should use.

After knowing this, here is an example:

`a.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const { expect } = chai;

describe('a', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(chai.request).to.be.a('function');
  });
});
```

`b.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const { expect } = chai;

describe('b', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(chai.request).to.be.a('function');
  });
});
```

`fixtures.js`:

```js
var chai = require('chai'),
  chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

exports.mochaGlobalSetup = function () {
  chai.use(chaiHttp);
  console.log('setup chaiHttp plugin');
};
```

Run the test suites and the result:

```
npx mocha --require fixtures.js ./**/*.test.js
setup chaiHttp plugin


  a
    ✓ should pass

  b
    ✓ should pass


  2 passing (5ms)
```

Comment: Thanks a million, man. This is cool